# Realizar update e insert no mysql via asp classic

Tags: mysql, asp, conexão

Bom dia Pessoal

Gostaria de uma ajuda meio chata pode ser ate algo meio banal

tenho uma pagina em asp conecta.asp da seguinte maneira

```
 <%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%

<%
dim conn

sub AbreConn()
'Criamos o objeto de conexão
Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 

'Abrimos uma conexão com o banco de dados
conn.Open("DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};SERVER=server;PORT=3306;DATABASE=database;USER=usuario;PASSWORD=senha;OPTION=3;")
conexao_executa=true 

end sub

sub fechaConn()
'Fechamos a conexão com o banco de dados
conn.Close() 
'Destruímos o objeto
Set conn = Nothing
end sub

'sub que executara comandos no bd
sub executaconexao(comando)
    if conexao_executa=false then
        call AbreConn
    end if
    response.Write(comando)
    set objComando = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    objComando.ActiveConnection = conn
    objComando.CommandText = comando
    objComando.Execute() 
    Set objComando = Nothing
    call fechaConn

end sub
%>
```

consigo executar os `select's` normalmente não da nenhum erro no entanto na hora de fazer um update ou insert ele não executa nada, e tambem não da erro algum.

se alguem tiver alguma dica do que pode ser feito agradeço.

segue abaixo como chamo o update na pagina envia.asp

```
sql ="update produtos set descricao_produto = '" & server.HTMLEncode(request.form("elm1")) & "' where codigo_chave = 32"

executaconexao(sql)
```

Comment: Como é a consulta é impressa na tela?

Comment: Se não dá erro algum, obviamente é porque tudo está sendo executado sem problemas. Verifique se realmente existe um registro com `codigo_chave = 32`, pois se não houver, não irá dar erro. Teste esse update, sem a cláusula `where`. Assim você irá confirmar que os registros estão sim sendo atualizados.

Comment: Ah, e pesquise sobre SQL Injection. :)

Comment: @ThiagoLunardi desculpa a demora na resposta acho que é referente a alguma permissão no banco pois utilizando em outro servidor foi feito o update normal tem alguma ideia de que tipo de permissão deve ter?

Comment: Bom, daí é uma duvida de mysql. Veja na [documentação sobre _grant_](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/grant.html). Deve resolver, se for essa a causa.

Answer (score 1):

Brother refiz seu código e espero ter ajudado mudei pouca coisa ok

O detalhe é que você na sub executaconexao() faz a verificação de um objeto que só existe em AbreConn(), logo não tem como checar o IF sem chamar a AbreConn() antes ok.

Utilizei o conn.execute() na sub executaconexao() para diminuir o código.

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>

<%
dim conn

sub AbreConn()
    'Criamos o objeto de conexão
    Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
    ''Abrimos uma conexão com o banco de dados
    'conn.Open("DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};SERVER=server;PORT=3306;DATABASE=database;USER=usuario;PASSWORD=senha;OPTION=3;")
    conexao_executa=true

    Servidor = "localhost"
    dsnName = "gsc" 'The name of the DSN
    dsnUser = "wilson" 'The username for the DSN
    dsnPass = "wilson26" 'The password for the DSN
    database = "gsc" 'The database to use
    stringer = "Provider=MSDASQL;Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver};Server="&Servidor&";Database="&database&";User="&dsnUser&";Password="&dsnPass&";Option=3;"
    conn.Open stringer
end sub

sub fechaConn()
    'Fechamos a conexão com o banco de dados
    conn.Close() 
    'Destruímos o objeto
    Set conn = Nothing
end sub

'sub que executara comandos no bd
sub executaconexao(comando)
    call AbreConn()
    if conexao_executa=false then       
        conn.execute(comando)
        response.write comando
        call fechaConn()
    end if
end sub

sql = "insert into gsc.cadastro_cargo(cargo) values('boina verde');"
executaconexao(sql)

%>
```

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda essa é uma outra solução mas o problema era com o banco o usuario que me fornecerção não podia fazer alterações no banco mas obrigado pela ajuda